# Increment a variable from jQuery .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm trying to make a game where basically you click the picture, it disappears, and then 1 is added to a javascript variable.

So, I have this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

and I have some pictures and when you click on them, they disappear. For example:

```
<center><p><img src="test.jpg" border="0"></p></center>
```

I just want it so that the code below, as you can see above, adds 1 to a javascript variable called picturesRemoved

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your top and bottom code bits are the same.  Was this on purpose?

Answer (score 4):

Define the variable (as a global most likely)

```
var picturesRemoved = 0;
```

Then increment inside your handler:

```
picturesRemoved++;
```

Overall:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var picturesRemoved = 0;        

    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        picturesRemoved++;
    });
});
```

Comment: ahh you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Given HTML like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="" class="showCount">Show Count</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="test.jpg" border="0">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="test.jpg" border="0">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You could use the following to do what you are trying to accomplish:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var picturesRemoved = 0;

    $('li').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        picturesRemoved++;
    });

    $('.showCount').click( function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(picturesRemoved);
    });
});
```

`var picturesRemoved = 0;` sets a default value to the variable and initializes it.
`picturesRemoved++;` will increment the value as an item is selected.

I also included a link and click handler that will show you the current value of the variable as an example of how you could use it in you JS later on.

`e.preventDefault();` will prevent the default action of the anchor. Otherwise the anchor will behave based on the set HREF value.
`alert(picturesRemoved);` uses the standard JS alert function to show the variable.